# Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile' Houndify

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, houndify

I am trying to incorporate Houndify API into my project. However my gradle file would not build.

I downloaded a sample project from their site and it worked normally. I am migrating codes from that project gradle file to mine.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "edu.drexel.cs.ptn32.pennapps"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("debug.keystore")
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        // The username and password for this repo is set below
        url 'https://houndify.com/maven/'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile ('hound.android:hound-sdk:0.2.15@aar'){
        transitive=true
    }

    compile ('hound.android:phrasespotter:1.4.0'){
        transitive=true
    }

}

setHoundifyMavenCredentials("user", "pw")

def setHoundifyMavenCredentials(username, password) {
    for (repo in repositories) {
        if (repo.properties.url.toString().equals("https://houndify.com/maven/")) {
            repo.properties.credentials.username = username
            repo.properties.credentials.password = password
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to hear you are having problems migrating the Houndify SDK into your app. To make things easier, we've just removed the password restriction on the https://houndify.com/maven/ website. This means you can remove the setHoundifyMavenCredentials() portion from your build.gradle file.  I suggest pulling the latest version of the Houndify sample app houndify-sdk-sample-0.2.17.zip and making sure it builds OK on your system, then all you should need to do is to add these lines to your build.gradle and it should pull in the Houndify libraries.

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://houndify.com/maven/'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile ('hound.android:hound-sdk:0.2.15@aar'){
        transitive=true
    }

    compile ('hound.android:phrasespotter:1.4.0'){
        transitive=true
    }
}
```

Finally make sure you Android build system is up-to-date.
Please let us know if you are still running into problems and thanks for your feedback.  http://www.soundhound.com/contact